# Displaying the popup menu when clicking the button part of the CMFCMenuButton

Tags: button, menu, mfc

I have seen this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997495/example-code-for-cmfcmenubutton) about how to use `CMFCButtonMenu` control.

I have also read the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubutton-class?view=vs-2019) about the control.

Example:

[image: Button Menu]

Clicking the drop down works correctly. However, to quote the aforementioned SO Answer:

> If **left side** of button is clicked, then event handler is called directly, **without showing a popup menu**.

How can I change this default behaviour? I want to **always display** the menu when they click **anywhere** on the button.

I should add that thus button is being displayed on a `CDialog` in a `CDialog` based application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked the **Default Click** property:

[image: DefaultClick]

Setting that to **False** provides the behaviour I need.

I saw this in the source for the class:

```
BOOL  m_bDefaultClick; // Allow default (on button text/image) processing
```

That made me go try the setting.